# How to make AssistoLab/DropDown datasource dynamic?

Tags: ios, iphone, drop-down-menu, swift3, dropdown

dropDown.dataSource = ["Car", "Motorcycle", "Truck"] //static

//Array which needs to be passed inside drop down datasource.

public var pMaster = ProductMaster

//how to pass dynamic array for datasource.

selectProduct.dataSource = ["Select product type","Industrial Lubricant","Automotive Lubricant","GREASES"]  //static

selectProduct.dataSource = pMaster         // error cannot assign [ProductMaster] to type [String]

Comment: Which property of `ProductMaster` you want to show with your drop down ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you have to assign array of String (`[String]`) to the datasource, not your custom object (`[ProductMaster]`).